# Reason for (type) in (type)function() if the output of function() is ignored

Tags: c, types

I was looking through the Linux kernel source code and in the file `init/main.c` I saw the line

```
(void) ksys_dup(0);
```

I was wondering why `(void)` is there. I've seen code like

```
char *str = (char *)malloc(len);
```

This makes sense, as malloc is declared to return a void pointer but the memory it allocates here needs to be pointed to by a char pointer. This does not explain the `ksys_dup()` line, as its return value isn't recorded.

`ksys_dup()` returns an integer, and there are function calls around that line whose returns also aren't recorded but don't have a type specified.

Comment: it is used to say explicitly that the return value is ignored

Comment: *This makes sense, as malloc is declared to return a void pointer but the memory it allocates here needs to be pointed to by a char pointer.* – no, especially with `*alloc()` it makes no sense since `void*` is implicitly convertible to all other pointer types. It just adds noise with no function.

Comment: See [Should I cast the result of `malloc()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/) for diverging opinions on the merits or otherwise of the cast for a memory allocation function.  Suffice to say, there are strong disagreements, but the majority is probably on the "don't cast" side (but the "it might hide that you've not declared `malloc()` by including `<stdlib.h>`" excuse is pathetic, and has been ever since C99 mandated that functions be declared before use — that's a problem with using compilers that only conform to archaic versions of the C standard).

Comment: @Swordfish I've never casted malloc() in my own code, but I've seen other developers do that and I was just using it as an example.

Comment: Precisely, the value **returned** is not used.   This is the use of the `(void)` cast, to avoid some compilers warning about a function returning a value that is dropped.  The case of `malloc()` I'm afraid is different, you are hidding the actual type returned with a cast (the type of malloc will be assumed by the compiler to be an `int` **if you make the mistake** of not including the proper header)  and that will hide the error shutting down the compiler warning (which makes the warning useles) See other comments for _Why should  you never cast the value returned by **malloc(3)**._